# Is it possible to grow a mango plant in the Phoenix climate?

Tags: fruit-trees, germination

I've been wanting to plant a mango seed; though I live in Phoenix, Arizona.

Firstly, would a mango seed actually grow in my area? Secondly, I'm pretty new to any kind of plant life. So, does anyone have any information on germinating and planting a mango seed?

Comment: There is a youtuber named VeganAthlete from Phoenix, Arizona who grow mango tree

Answer (score 9):

As to germinating, the information that I can find says to plant with the rounded end up. Wrap it in a damp paper towel in a baggie and keep it someplace warm for a week to a month. Check it to make sure it doesn't mold. If it starts to mold, take it out and plant it.

But that has little to do with where you live. I could get Mango to *germinate* here in zone 5.

Mango is hardy to zone 10-11. Phoenix is zone 9. You may have trouble with winter kill.

You *might* be able to make it work if you have a site (or can create a microclimate) that stays warmer. Or if you can find a variety of mango (if such a thing exists, I don't know) that is hardier than the zone 10-11 that I found listed.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to suggest you take the advice of those who are local to you, they will have more first hand experience than those who might suggest that non-native varieties are too difficult.  So, many people, myself included, have successfully grown fruiting mango trees in Phoenix.  The suggestion not to grow from a seed is a good one, you should get a grafted variety because it's unlikely that a seed from even a tasty mango will produce a fruit that's good eating, due to the nature of the seeds.  Make sure it gets plenty of water.  Mangos can handle all the Phoenix summer sun you can throw at it.  In the wintertime, when it drops under 40 degrees, water it and lay a cover over it at night so it'll stay warm.  A little luck and a little elbow grease is all that's needed.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find the link, but I remember reading that the best eating mangoes are clones from well-established, known-to-be-tasty mango trees. Branches are grafted on to rootstock and allowed to grow.

I'm still waiting to find out in my 3 year old mango tree's fruit will be good (I didn't know about the clone thing when I planted it).

Answer (score 5):

I have been successful growing mangos from the fruit seeds in Scottsdale, Arizona. Let the husk dry (overnight) and then carefully cut an edge on one side to remove the seed. Only in warm weather, plant the seed in well drained soil, water it every day and within 2 weeks you will know if the seed is viable. The seedling can tolerate some sun during the day but that's it. Best to give it filtered light. The same goes for the tree as it grows. If it is standing in water it will die. The tree, if in the ground, will die back to the soil line in a freeze but usually will come back in the spring. In a large pot it can be brought into shelter. Any frost or near freezing temps will hurt it. I once had a tree (more of a skinny twig) blossom and had a baby mango which blew off in heavy wind. Perhaps around the area of the zoo, downtown Phoenix, the airport and the Scottsdale Civic Center Mall where frosts are rare a mango tree could survive. There are rubber trees out in the open and these are sensitive to cold. They can be a guide where the warmer zones are. Microclimates such as the area on the south side of the senate office building provides enough warmth that a full grown royal palm grows in the palm garden there. Good luck.

Comment: Not too many woody perennials will 'come back' if 'killed back'...microclimates are important for marginal zone plants...send some pics or more details about the mango trees that were successful...!

Answer (score 3):

The mango is a tropical plant. So not only do you need the heat and lack of frost, but you will also need water and humidity - something Phoenix does not naturally have.

If you had a big enough greenhouse (!) it should be possible but note Kevin's comment about clones. This applies to pretty much all the fruit trees I can think of. Yes you might be able to grow a mango stone in a similar way that an grocer's avocado can be grown but it is unlikely to be like the original fruit. Cuttings & rooting stock is the way to go if you want a reproducible fruit and tree.

Also as a good general guide, beware of a certain amount of wishful thinking on the part of the stores when they advertise their "non-local" trees. I was buying agaves from the local gardening center at the weekend - most of the ones they had would be killed by even a mild local winter. Luckily they had some hardier ones which should survive okay.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old post but in case someone else is looking for info I will comment.
It is okay to grow from seed as long as the seed is Poly-embryonic. You can research which varieties are.  Ataulfo would be an example.
The seedling will need to stay away from direct sunlight here in the valley, and it will need a lot of care for a few years. i.e. summer sun protection, lots of water (but not soggy) and winter protection below 40 degrees. You can slowly acclimate the plant over the course of a few years. Planting it in dappled sunlight is a good way to grow it. Jacaranda trees work great for this, just remember that your mango will get tall so don't plant it to close. Also go onto Youtube and research it.